# Can we customize CakePHP test page?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

In http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html, says we can see tests using `http://localhost/your_app/test.php` page. Can we customize the appearance (css, layout) CakePHP test page? I know it is found in TestSuite/Templates folder but Is there a way to override it?

Please anyone help!

Thanks

Comment: how do you mean? customize the apperance? change the css.

Comment: Change the text and change the layout and also the css.

Comment: These are at lib/Cake/TestSuite/templates I do not know if there is a way to override them.

Comment: I have seen those but I want if there is a way to override them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paths to the layout files (`lib/Cake/TestSuite/templates`) used are hard coded in the so called "reporter" used by the test suite, see the `paint*()` methods [**`CakeHtmlReporter`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Reporter/CakeHtmlReporter.php).

It is however possible to hook in a custom reporter, by creating an appropriate reporter class named `HtmlReporter` in `app/TestSuite/Reporter`, ie `app/TestSuite/Reporter/HtmlReporter.php`

If present, the test suite will use this over the Cake HTML reporter. So you could simply extend the Cake HTML reporter, and override the `paint*()` methods so that they make use your custom templates.

If you'd want to use custom `phpunit.php`, `xdebug.php` and `missing_configuration.php` templates too, then you'd also have to use a custom test suite dispatcher, see [**`CakeTestSuiteDispatcher`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php). The build in dispatcher can easibly be exchanged for a custom one in your `app/webroot/test.php` file.

Comment: If you think the question is useful, please vote up.